# Dihedral group for arbitrary polygon

Tags: abstract-algebra, dihedral-groups

Is a dihedral group only considered for shapes that when reflected or rotated fit exactly back into place of the original image?

My confusion arises from this wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group#The_dihedral_group_as_symmetry_group_in_2D_and_rotation_group_in_3D) and specifically from this picture:

[image]

Are these symmetries considered a dihedral group?

Comment: Did you see the notes by K. Conrad?

Comment: Yes, I didn't read it all since I was just glimpsing through wikipedia and had some questions.

Answer (score 1):

Those four *actions* form a dihedral group of order $4$. They are not symmetries of the letter "F" though, they are symmetries of a line segment (2-gon). The rotations are applied to the letter "F" in the picture to help you see what they do. If they are symmetries of anything in the picture, they are symmetries of the $y$-axis (or the $x$-axis).

Comment: So just to clarify, the letter 'F' object does not have symmetries and therefore is not a dihedral group?

Comment: A dihedral group is a collection of _actions_, not a shape. It is the collection of actions that demonstrate the symmetry of regular polygons embedded in a plane. The letter "F"'s symmetry group (if you view that as a 2D shape embedded in the plane) is just the one-element group, with the do-nothing identity action being its only member.

Comment: So any non-symmetric polygon's dihedral group is just the identity action?

Answer (score -1):

The dihedral group specifically refers to the symmetries of a regular polygon, so an $n$-gon under any transformation in the dihedral group $D_n$ is mapped to itself. I think the picture in this article is using an $F$ for illustrative purposes, since an $F$ has $no$ symmetry; thus you can see that switching the order of transformations really does make a difference (this would be more difficult to show on an actual square, which is symmetric, so they would need to color the vertices/edges or something like that).

Answer (score -2):

Look, Michael, dihedral groups are easy, they are the next best thing after a cyclic group. While in a cyclic group you turn things around in a circle, see your dihedral group as a prism, like two identical cycles above each other, forming a kind of coin. Then your movements consist in turning the coin as if it were cyclic, and the extra moves being the flips of the coin and consider the "F" as a symbol stamped through the coin.